# How to select columns that have name beginning with same prefix?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 8.1.11, is there a way to select a set of columns that have name beginning with same prefix.

Suppose we have columns : PREFIX_col1, PREFIX_col2, ...

Is it possible to do a request like :

```
SELECT 'PREFIX_*' FROM mytable;
```

Which of course doesn't work.

Comment: You could possibly construct a function to build up the query, and then use EXECUTE

Comment: Good idea, i'm gonna explore this way.

Comment: ***8.1***? Really? You should upgrade **now**. That version has long been de-supported. Btw: your table structure seems to indicate that your tables are not normalized. You might want to consider a redesign.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Check the question date.

Comment: @muistooshort: Oh (slaps head). I didn't see that. It showed up at the top of the list (although 8.1 wasn't really up-to-date int 2010 either...)

Answer (score 5):

`information_schema.COLUMNS` contains all the columns in your DB so you can query for a specific pattern in the name like this:

```
select c.COLUMN_NAME 
  from information_schema.COLUMNS as c 
 where c.TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' 
   and c.COLUMN_NAME like 'PREFIX_%';
```

Comment: Please understand that "code only" answers are discouraged - rather add a bit of explanation. And read about *formatting* your input!

Comment: This is no help, because that query itself only gives you datasets - you're still unable to turn that into a set of columns you want to have with your actual query.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to construct the query with a query and use EXECUTE. Its a little easier w/ 8.3+. Here's a query that will run on 8.1 and pulls all columns starting with r%
from the film table

```
$$
DECLARE 
   qry  TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT 'SELECT ' || substr(cols, 2, length(cols) - 2) ||
      ' FROM film' INTO qry
    FROM (
        SELECT array(
            SELECT quote_ident(column_name::text)
            FROM information_schema.columns 
            WHERE table_schema = 'public'
              AND table_name = 'film'
              AND column_name LIKE 'r%'
            ORDER BY ordinal_position
        )::text cols 
        -- CAST text so we can just strip off {}s and have column list
    ) sub;

    EXECUTE qry;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like  [the syntax description of PostgreSQL 8.x's SELECT statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html) does not allow this.  A SELECT list must be an expression or list of expressions, and the syntax for [expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-expressions.html) does not seem to allow for wildcarded partial column names.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for response, it seems you're right. Too bad for me :-(