# Postgresql select columns if the columns include substring

Tags: postgresql

Say I have two tables (Color, Fruit)  with the following columns (yellow, orange, apple, desk, sky1, sky2, sky3 .. sky15).

And I made a query

```
SELECT Color.yellow AS Yellow, Fruit.orange AS Orange, Color.sky* 
FROM Color 
  LEFT JOIN Fruit ON Color.Yellow = Fruit.orange
```

to get all sky* columns.
But of course, it didn't work.

How can I get the all the sky* columns without typing all the sky* columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select columns that have name beginning with same prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941156/how-to-select-columns-that-have-name-beginning-with-same-prefix)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTihanyi Not really. as I need to use other tables at the same time. Such as by using LEFT JOIN

Comment: No, this is not possible. But typically SQL GUI clients have some kind of auto completion where this would be very easy.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hmmm Thanks anyway. But I don't use SQL GUI. I may have to type all the sky* or just use * and then delete the other columns

Comment: @DonggyunKim Maybe you spent more time here than just writing the code -:) ?

Comment: @pifor haha maybe. But my real table has about 100 columns. sooo ;;

Comment: The real question is: why do you have so many identical columns that have increasing numbers? More often than not, this indicates a bad database design that requires proper normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ease your pain I propose a small remedy:

```
select string_agg('sky' || i, ', ') from generate_series(1,100) as i;
                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                    string_agg                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 sky1, sky2, sky3, sky4, sky5, sky6, sky7, sky8, sky9, sky10, sky11, sky12, sky13, sky14, sky15, sky16, sky17, sky18, sky19, sky20, sky21, sky22, sky23, sky24, sky25, sky26, sky27, sky28, sky29
, sky30, sky31, sky32, sky33, sky34, sky35, sky36, sky37, sky38, sky39, sky40, sky41, sky42, sky43, sky44, sky45, sky46, sky47, sky48, sky49, sky50, sky51, sky52, sky53, sky54, sky55, sky56, sk
y57, sky58, sky59, sky60, sky61, sky62, sky63, sky64, sky65, sky66, sky67, sky68, sky69, sky70, sky71, sky72, sky73, sky74, sky75, sky76, sky77, sky78, sky79, sky80, sky81, sky82, sky83, sky84,
 sky85, sky86, sky87, sky88, sky89, sky90, sky91, sky92, sky93, sky94, sky95, sky96, sky97, sky98, sky99, sky100
(1 row)

#
```