# How to Select some fields have same prefix Names

Tags: sql, delphi, firedac

Using Firedac, is there a way to select a set of columns that have name beginning with same prefix? 

Suppose we have columns Fields : PREFIX_col1, PREFIX_col2, ...

Is it possible to do a request like :

```
SELECT 'PREFIX_*' FROM mytable;
```

i have this Table: [`USERS`] has `07 Fields`:

```
 - ID (PRIMARY kEY)
 - USER_NickName
 - USER_Password
 - EMAIL_Recovery
 - REG_Insert_DateTime
 - REG_Edit_DateTime
 - PICTURE
```

I need to Select just TWO Fields using Query like that:

```
SELECT USER.* FROM USERS
```

what i mean Above is to load into my Query just this TWO Fields:

```
 - USER_NickName
 - USER_Password
```

WHERE they have the same PREFIX NAME !!
i know that my Query SELECT Above is Wrong, but is there a way to SELECT Fields without writing All fields names using just the Prefix they have ?
...
Very **IMPORTANT** Note:
//========================================================//
// < PLZ: My QUESTION IS About `FIREDAC` and Not About `Native SQL Statements` ..!!  > //
//========================================================//

Comment: No: SELECT cannot filter columns, only datasets.

Comment: @AmigoJack and what about `information_schema.columns` ?

Comment: Just using some logic, if you just use the prefix how it will determine which column you want the Query to be applied?

Comment: You put dots in field names? Really?

Comment: @AmigoJack  In Sql, it is perfectly valid to specifu a subset of columns in a Select.

Comment: @Olivier I TRY IT and it works for me without any ERRORS ..., but the query must be first like that `SELECT USERS.* FROM USERS` and this will load all fields in that table

Comment: How do you reckon your Table has 5 columns?  It has seven, ID..Picture.

Comment: @Roberto that is still filtering datasets, not columns. @MartynA yes: specify. But not filter. `SELECT t.di*k FROM table AS t` is not allowed in any DBMS I ever encountered.

Comment: @Roberto you can use dbschema’s te get the filednames of a table. But that’s dbvendor specific. A simple way to get info about the fields/types of a tabel is to use `select top 0 * from table` - works with de sqlbased db vendors I’ve used so far.

Comment: I have not checked but it may be that FDac allows the identifier before the dot because it assumes that it is a table alias which will be resolved by the RDMS.

Comment: @AmigoJack:  Is what yu are meaning to say is that SQL does not do pattern-matching to resolve wild-carded partial column names?

Comment: @MartynA Yes: only `SELECT t.* FROM table AS t` is allowed to get ALL columns from that table - otherwise you have to fully SPECIFY the columns you want. Short form: `SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: @R.Hoek and how are you able to combine that info into only selecting specific columns? I mean: if we want to know the table's column names we can query the table itself - that still doesn't help us to FILTER BY column name.

Comment: I would suggest using a SQL IDE that does code completion and expansion either by itself or with add-ins. Write and test queries there before using them in your Delphi projects.

Comment: Wait - why does this question have identical text and examples just like [this Q from almost 11 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3941156/4299358)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select columns that have name beginning with same prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941156/how-to-select-columns-that-have-name-beginning-with-same-prefix)

Comment: @AmigoJack Simply, Because my Question is BASED from that Very OLD Question, where my is Universal and while the VERY OLD is talks About PostgreSQL and Specific Version !!

Comment: @DelphiCoder Unfortunatly Not !!, and that was just a Base IDEA of my Universal Question..

Comment: @AmigoJack with the returned info the OP can create a SQL dynamically. Like `var sql = 'SELECT ' + GetFieldNamesWithPrefix('PREFIX_','Table') + ' FROM Table WHERE x = y` resulting into `SELECT PREFIX_Field1, PREFIX_Field2 FROM Table WHERE x = y` (note: `GetFieldNamesWithPrefix` should return the required fields using the method described by me) - but to be clear, there's no way sql will understand wildcard fieldnames: it's just the `*` for all fields OR the specific fields specified by name.

Comment: @R.Hoek a good IDEA

Answer (score -2):

in Sqlite we can do this :

```
SELECT 
  "SELECT " || GROUP_CONCAT(NAME) || "  FROM USERS"
  FROM
  PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO("USERS")
  WHERE SUBSTR(NAME, 1, 5)= "USER_"
```

## RESULT:

```
SELECT USER_NickName,USER_Password  FROM USERS
```

the Result Above is a Ready to use Query inside our Result Query Above
=======
i hope this Help to Solve All Firedac Databases that Support!!
=======
Unfortunately i have not tested with Others DataBases now..

Comment: How is this an answer? You don't get any results from your table but instead only one dataset of text - that's what you could have achieved with `information_schema` already. You still don't actually query your table.

Comment: @AmigoJack yes ofcourse, but like i sad in my Sub_Answer(not the Total Answer), the Result Above is a Ready to use Query inside our Result Query Above...

Comment: Just repeating the text from your answer doesn't add any value. The Q is "select some fields", not "create query text". This answer's query is basically the same as [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45303354/4299358), just with [SQLite's `group_concat()` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#group_concat). Are you sure you know what you actually want?

Comment: @AmigoJack should i Delete my Sub Answer while i can't Post like that Infos inside the COMMENT SECTION ABOVE

Comment: I agree with @AmigoJack to the extent that this answer doesn't match the original question.  However, the real reason your q and this answer have attracted so much discussion without reaching a definite conclusion is that the q is not sufficiently clear - you seemed to be expecting a solution which uses SQL to generate a SQL-executable query to deliver the final result, but did not definitively say so in your q.  However, it is trivial to use Delphi code to construct a query which uses an arbitrary list of SELECT columns chosen by whatever criteria you like.

Comment: @MartynA yes i totally Agree with both of you, but my SUB_Answer above i think is Able to be a Useful Info and an IDEA in order to solve my Question Above ..